# Find applications causing a particular advertisement and get rid of latter?

Tags: ads

See screenshot:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

That  ad seems to be the the one causing any application to die abruptly for absolutely nothing.

I saw that ad when I was using Skype. I also saw it when I was playing Clash of Clans and other games.

How do I get rid of it? What applications have that ad?

**EDIT:**

- I restored factory settings and an app tried to ask permission to send ads. I click cancel. After a while that app tried to ask permission again. I have no idea what ad it is.
- I did a factory reset. Now the ad is gone. However it is replaced by annoying permission request.

The problem with the permission is it's not clear which app ask for that permission.

[image: IMG:]

Also, I do not think this question is a duplicate because I got the problem even after factory reset and I see that this app is supported by airpush notification. Obviously, as a user, I just want to delete the app. What app?

Furthermore, I can't scan my Android. Every scanner, malware anti virus, airpush detector fails and crashes.

I think some apps are embedded in my ROM. That's why the price is a bit cheaper.

Comment: This is the second question I have seen of you dealing with sketchy behavior of your phone. You might want to flash on a new ROM, seeing from your comments on the other post. Your device is obviously a rip-off, and may be filled to the brim with adware and spying programs.

Comment: How do I flash on a new ROM?

Comment: I think you're right. I restore factory setting and "an app" tried to ask permission to send ads. I click cancel. After a while that app tried to ask permission again. I have no idea what ads it is.